# Firing Event on particular queue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using **laravel 5.1** and I am creating event which I want it to be **queued**,but i don't want it to be queued on the **default** queue.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You mean using multiple queue drivers?

Comment: yes i mean multiple queue